# Not able to remove the default namespace prefix during marshallingl a POJO object using the org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.3 package

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, glassfish

I am trying to marshalling a POJO object using the org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime in spring boot application

```
public String createXML() {
   Person person = new Person("John", "Doe");

  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
   Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
   marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

 NamespacePrefixMapper prefixMapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {

   @Override
   public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
               return "";
            }
 };

 marshaller .setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper", prefixMapper);

 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 mar.marshal(auaRequest, sw);

return sw.toString();

}
```

Getting response as `<ns2:Pesron>.....</ns2:Pesron>`

I wanted `<Person> ... </Person>`

I tried using QName

```
QName personRoot = new QName("myNameSpace", "Person", "");
```

I passed empty string for the prefix (last parameter).

```
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<>(personRoot , Person.class, person), new StreamResult(sw));
```

`sw.toString()` is still getiing ns2 as prefix.

I expected no prefix to my output xml.